# Sequentially run ruby scripts in a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a directory of *.rb files that I would like to run, but sequentially and not in parallel.  My thoughts are to have a master file which calls each file, but how can I force it to wait until the process is finished before running the next file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dir['*.rb'].each{ |f| load(f) }
```

Each file will be fully run; the code will not continue to the next iteration until the current file is fully loaded and executed.

*The only caveat to this would be if you have a file that launches a new Thread and does not `.join` it; the Ruby file would normally exit before the Thread is finished; in this case the next file will begin being loaded while the Thread continues to run.*

**Edit**: If you need to run arbitrary command line code from Ruby, you can simply do:

```
Dir['*.rb'].each{ |f| `rails r #{f}` }
```

Again, the Kernel [backtick command](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60) will wait until the process is complete before returning.

Comment: I found [a solution](https://gist.github.com/1405766), but I like your a lot more.  Thanks!!

Comment: @GreggoryRothmeier The solution you linked to runs the files under `rails`; do you need to actually launch new Rails sites (which won't shut down on their own), or just run normal Ruby code?

Comment: I just came back to ask you about that.  I do need to run the scripts with "rails r".  Is there a concise way of doing that or should I use my method (but with looping i.e. [here](https://gist.github.com/1405798))?

Comment: @GreggoryRothmeier The gist you have linked to seems like a reasonable way to accomplish your needs. Alternatively, see my edit.